# Detect roaming (switching the Access Point) with QtMobility?

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, nokia, qt-mobility

I need to write an application, that detects roaming from one access point to another if I'm connected to WLAN. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything that detects roaming for me. All I could find are some explanations in the [Bearer API](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0/bearer-management.html). One sentence says:

> The second form of roaming is referred
>   to as Forced Roaming. The system
>   simply changes the link layer without
>   consulting the application. It is up
>   to the application to detect that some
>   of its internal socket may have become
>   invalid.

Since I'm not a network guy I don't have any idea how I could track roaming. It would be enough to know, that the device switched from one access point to another.

Maybe anybody of you can help me out on that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is exactly the thing you need:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0/qnetworksession.html#newConfigurationActivated

Comment: Thx. Must have overseen that (I've already tried it with stateChanged, but that didn't work for me).
I will try it out and give feedback.

Comment: It seems, that this only works when my device switches the network. What I want to achieve is to get notified when my device switches Access Points INSIDE one network.

Let's say you have a home network with 3 access points (one in each floor). you are in the first floor connected to your network on access point 1. now you go upstairs and access point 2 offers a better signal strength than access point 1. now your device will switch to access point 2. and this is the event I want to catch.

Answer (score 0):

Check out RConnectionMonitor and MConnectionMonitorObserver classes.
THey allow your code to get notified when connections change